# How to delete macOS startup action of network connection attempt to a remote server

Tags: network, startup

I am on Monterey macOS 12.3.1. I receive this message every time at restart.

How can I delete this startup action? I looked at /Library/LaunchAgents but cannot find there. I also checked **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > **Login Items**, no luck.

[image]

Comment: Check in your network configuration for proxy or dns

Comment: I noticed that this can be part of Profile installed by my employer. How can I make sure if it is?